# Add attributes to DataColumn

Tags: c#, ado.net, metadata

I am creating a reporting component that takes an `IEnumerable` input and performs some transformations and aggregations and returns a new `IEnumerable` with a dynamic number of columns. I am using ADO.NET for this because it is easy to create a `DataTable` with the appropriate columns.

The transformed `IEnumerable` is sent to a reporting visualization component that uses information stored in Attributes to format the results nicely. It's not necessary to be able to remove or change the attributes once they have been applied.

My question is this: 
Is it possible to associate an `Attribute` with a `DataColumn` so that the `PropertyDescriptor` emitted by the ADO.NET `DataView` includes these Attributes?

Follow-up question:
If this is not possible with ADO.NET are there other libraries that I can use to accomplish this?

Edit: Update for clarity
I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn example = dt.Columns.Add("Test",typeof(double));

//This is the functionality I am looking for ideally
example.AddAttribute(new CustomAttribute("Hello"));

public class CustomAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Comment: I've generally used DataView.Table.Columns[] to get this information when I needed it...  Are you somehow using DataViews that aren't associated with backing tables?

Comment: @ebyrob No I'm using a DataView in the standard way. I want to be able to tag my DataColumns with Attributes

Comment: How is DataView.Table not standard?  (That combined with ExtendedProperties will give you this ability, the only problems I can think of might arise if you're serializing your DataView between creation and use which limits what kind of ExtendedProperties you can get away with storing)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [ExtendedProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.extendedproperties.aspx) property on DataColumns. This allows you to add custom data to a datacolumn. You would have to write the code that uses this custom data yourself, however - the formatting (or what ever you intend the data to be used for) isn't automatic.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm aware of ExtendedProperties but I was specifically looking to make the PropertyDescriptor aware of them. +1 for effort

Comment: Please note that the documentation states: "*Properties that are not of type String are not persisted when the DataColumn is written as XML*". So it seems you can store everyting, but just strings are persisted.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question: It's not possible to inject attributes into a DataColumn and have them appear in the PropertyDescriptor that DataView's implementation of ITypedList emits